# What are alternate ways of selecting elements in python selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

The element in this html is dynamic:

```
<textarea class="Medium" id="z46a662fd68e143128cd31e6978f63a5c" 
name="Description" placeholder="" data-val-length="Character limit (8000) 
exceeded" data-val-length-max="8000" data-val-editor-
id="z46a662fd68e143128cd31e6978f63a5c" data-val-position="0"></textarea>
```

I am unable to use this code in my script more than once:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('z46a662fd68e143128cd31e6978f63a5c')
```

With the code below, I was able to find the element by name - but unable to use send_keys to input data.

```
driver.find_element_by_name('Description')
```

I'd like to know more than one workaround for this type of issue - Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement is not a proper CSS selector, hence it fails. If you wanted to choose by CSS, you could specify it like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('textarea#z46a662fd68e143128cd31e6978f63a5c')
```

Or you could search by ID, if ID is **static**:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('z46a662fd68e143128cd31e6978f63a5c')
```

However it looks like your ID is dynamic, in which case looking up by name, like you did, is actually the best approach.

To send keys, you can:

```
driver.find_element_by_name('Description').send_keys("Hello")
```

If that doesn't work, make sure page loaded and `textarea` is rendered. You may need to use [Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html):

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.Name, "Description"))
element.send_keys("Hello")
```